# How can I make each a tag display a different chunk of text when clicked in a separate div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
<aside class="side_article_content"><p id="defaultText">Chakras are blah blah blah</p>
    <p id="baseChakraInfo" style="display:none;">Base Chakra blah blah blah</p>
    <p id="sacralChakraInfo" style="display:none;">Sacral Chakra blah blah blah</p>
    <p id="solarPlexusChakraInfo" style="display:none;">Solar Plexus Chakra blah blah blah</p>
    <p id="heartChakraInfo" style="display:none;">Heart Chakra blah blah blah</p>
    <p id="throatChakraInfo" style="display:none;">Throat Chakra blah blah blah</p>
    <p id="browChakraInfo" style="display:none;">Brow Chakra blah blah blah</p>
    <p id="crownChakraInfo" style="display:none;">Crown Chakra blah blah blah</p></aside>
    </div>   
<div class="main">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="base" onClick="showBase(this);" class="_base">Base or Root</a></li>
                <li><a id="sacral" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showSacral(this);"  class="_sacral" >Sacral</a></li>
                <li><a id="solarPlexus" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showSolarPlexus(this);" class="_solar">Solar Plexus</a></li>
                <li><a id="heart" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showHeart(this);" class="_heart" >Heart</a></li>
                <li><a id="throat" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showThroat(this);" class="_throat">Throat</a></li>
                <li><a id="brow" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showBrow(this);" class="_brow">Brow</a></li>
                <li><a id="crownChakra" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showCrownChakra(this);" class="chakra_crown" title="Crown Chakra">Crown Chakra - Pineal gland, regulates biological cycles, including sleep.</a></li>                                                                        
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I had some javascript below which was really messy, and it worked almost to perfection. It worked if I click on each a tag from top to bottom, the text in each p tag displays and once the next one is clicked, the previous disappears - which is what I wanted. However, if I click each a tag from bottom to top, the text of each p tag is always present and it does not disappear. It also does not work if you click on each a tag at random. What I want is to be able to click on each a tag and only the corresponding p tag to appear. I did not want to post my JS code here cuz I am new to it and its really long and messy. If you need I can post it later

```
<script>
        function showBase(text) {
            if(text.id == "base") {
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function showSacralChakra(text) {
            if(text.id == "sacralChakra") {
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function showSolarPlexus(text) {
            if(text.id == "solarPlexus") {
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function showHeart(text) {
            if(text.id == "heart") {
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function showThroat(text) {
            if(text.id == "throat") {
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function showBrow(text) {
            if(text.id == "brow") {
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function showCrown(text) {
            if(text.id == "crown") {
                document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("defaultText").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("baseChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("sacralChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("solarPlexusChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("heartChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("throatChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("browChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("crownChakraInfo").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Not going to be able to help you without your JS code

Comment: So I edited my post and pasted my JS code. Please dont go nuts on me for how messy it is. I am sure there is a much shorter way to do this, but I am a newby. Thanks in advance ken4z

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Everyone starts somewhere. I created a JS Fiddle that has the behavior you are looking for and greatly simplifies your JS. https://jsfiddle.net/

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions